# Enumerator skipping elements. Unable to figure out why

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, enums

I'm experiencing this weird bug in which Enumerator skips the middle element object. Been wrecking my brain on this. http://pastie.org/6636093

```
@job.data['dj_ids'] = [1,2,3]
dj_ids = @job.data['dj_ids'] # => [1,2,3]

dj_ids.each do |t|
  puts t
  @job.data['dj_ids'].delete(t)
end

# Output:
# 1
# 3

# @job.data['dj_ids'] => [2]
```

Its so strange that [2] never even gets called hence not deleted. I can't seem to figure out what could be the reason.

MRI Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `dj_ids = @job.data['dj_ids']` `dj_ids` is just a reference, so when you do `@job.data['dj_ids'].delete(t)` you delete and element and `dj_ids[1]` becomes 3

you can do `dj_ids = @job.data['dj_ids'].dup` to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

It is because both dj_ids and @job.data['dj_ids'] are reffering to same object. So you are iterating and deleting at the same time.

You can change the second line to dj_ids = @job.data['dj_ids'].clone or dj_ids = @job.data['dj_ids'].dup and it should work